# cset shield fails to execute task on a shielded core

Tags: cpu, benchmark

I'm trying to run a benchmark on a shielded core on x86-64 (4 cores) and Ubuntu 22.04. Shielding core 3 runs fine:

```
paul@cube-ubuntu-22:~/simd-agner/build$ sudo cset shield -c 3
cset: --> activating shielding:
cset: moving 714 tasks from root into system cpuset...
[==================================================]%
cset: "system" cpuset of CPUSPEC(0-2) with 714 tasks running
cset: "user" cpuset of CPUSPEC(3) with 0 tasks running
```

but trying to run my benchmark on it fails:

```
paul@cube-ubuntu-22:~/simd-agner/build$ cset shield -e ./bench-native-icx 
cset: **> 1 tasks are not movable, impossible to move
cset: --> last message, executed args into cpuset "/user", new pid is: 10578
```

and the benchmark runs on core 1 instead of core 3. There is no problems when I use `taskset`:

```
taskset -c 3 ./bench-native-icx
```

which runs the benchmark on core 3 as expected. I'm looking at another terminal running `watch grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo` to determine, which core is being used. It shows it unambiguously.